# Output Multiple RegEx matches to another array using powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I'm new to Powershell and trying parse multiple strings (non-delimited) using RegEx.  Default RegEx output uses $matches, so trying to save values from 1st string, 2nd string, 3rd string, etc.. so I can use "parsed" values later.

I can't figure out how to run and save output from multiple lines into new array so I can retrieve values later?

1. Set RegEx match string
2. Set 1 to many $string variables
3. Set 1 $total variable combining many $string variables form step 2.
4. Foreach variable IN $total, run RegEx to parse string into separate values

```
#Work
$regex = "([A-Z]*\..*\.[A-Z]?) (?:\s*) ([A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([A-Z]{2}) (\d*)/(\d) (\d)"

$string01 = "DEV.This_Is_Command_JobA.C               Jun 7, 2016 07:33:35 Jun 7, 2016 07:59:22 SU 84534137/1 0"
$string02 = "DEV.This_Is_Command_JobB.C               Jun 8, 2016 08:33:35 Jun 8, 2016 08:59:22 SU 84534138/1 0"
$string03 = "DEV.This_Is_Command_JobC.C               Jun 9, 2016 09:33:35 Jun 9, 2016 09:59:22 SU 84534139/1 0"     

$total = $string01,$string02,$string03

Foreach ($_ in $total)
{ 
  $_ -match $regex 
} 

#check work
$matches
```

Desired Output:

```
    7     0                           
    6     1                           
    5     84534139                    
    4     SU                          
    3     Jun 7, 2016 07:59:22        
    2     Jun 7, 2016 07:33:35        
    1     DEV.This_Is_Command_JobA.C  
    0     DEV.This_Is_Command_JobA.C 

    7     0                           
    6     1                           
    5     84534139                    
    4     SU                          
    3     Jun 8, 2016 08:59:22        
    2     Jun 8, 2016 08:33:35        
    1     DEV.This_Is_Command_JobB.C  
    0     DEV.This_Is_Command_JobB.C 

    7     0                           
    6     1                           
    5     84534139                    
    4     SU                          
    3     Jun 9, 2016 09:59:22        
    2     Jun 9, 2016 09:33:35        
    1     DEV.This_Is_Command_JobC.C  
    0     DEV.This_Is_Command_JobC.C 

    So I can retrieve values such as an example:
    $matchesA[0-7]
    $matchesB[0-7]
    $matchesC[0-7]
```

Comment: so whats the question?

Comment: `$Result = @( $total | % { [Regex]::Match($_, $regex) } )`

Comment: Please highlight main question clearly, Not so clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Declare the strings as an array:**

  ```
  $strings = @(
      "................."
      "................."
      "................."
  )
  ```

  Then collect `$matches` using a `foreach` loop:

  ```
  $results = foreach ($s in $strings) {
      $s -match $regex >$null;
      ,$matches
  }
  ```

  or `$results = $strings | %{ $s -match $regex >$null; ,$matches }` for brevity.

  Now you can access $results[0] as $results[0][0], $results[0][1] for $strings[0] and so on.
- **Declare the strings as a hashtable to use names:**

  ```
  $strings = @{
      A="................."
      B="................."
      C="................."
  }

  $results = @{}
  foreach ($item in $strings.GetEnumerator()) {
      $item.value -match $regex >$null
      $results[$item.name] = $matches
  }
  ```

  Now you can access $results.A as $results.A[0], $results.A[1] for $strings.A and so on.

Notes:

- `$s -match $regex` populates the built-in `$matches` hashtable with the results for current string and returns a boolean $true or $false which we don't need in the output so `>$null` discards it.
- `,$matches` is a shorthand for `@($matches)` to handle the case of empty $matches and still output it as one empty element in `$results`, otherwise it would be skipped thus reducing the number of elements in $results.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!